# MySQL not updating in time to echo updated records

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a form that retrieves information about a user from a database and allows the user to change it, basically an update profile page. However, I have one form that does not seem to update.

Below is a simplified version of my form code with fewer fields

```
<form id="update_profile" action="" method="post"> 
<fieldset><legend>Account Information</legend>

    <label>First*</label><br />
    <input name="fName" type="text" id="fName" maxlength="50" value="<?php echo  $current_user->user_firstname ?>"  />
    <br />

    <!-- Other fields here that update with no problem -->

    <label>Email*</label><br />
    <input name="email1" type="text" id="email1" maxlength="50" value="<?php echo  $current_user->user_email ?>" />

    <label>Confirm Email*</label><br />
    <input name="email2" type="text" id="email2" maxlength="50" value="<?php echo  $current_user->user_email ?>"/>

</fieldset>
</form>
```

Below is my PHP Post code for updating the database

```
$loggedInAs = $current_user->ID;
$fName = $wpdb->escape($_POST['fName']);
$email1 = $wpdb->escape($_POST['email1']);
$email2 = $wpdb->escape($_POST['email2']);

    // Code to check that the emails match & are valid email addresses

$user_id = wp_update_user(array(
    'ID'         => $loggedInAs,
    'first_name' => $fName,
    'user_email'  => $email1,
));
```

The problem is that when I update the email address the page reloads with a "your information has been saved" message but displays the old email address until the page refreshes. This doesn't happen with any other field on the page, from the first one to the last one, and I'm pulling my hair out trying to figure out why that is because I can't see any difference in the code. Does anybody have any suggestions? I know the database updates every time, correctly, because if I refresh the page then there's no problem with it ever displaying the updated emails, or throwing an error if the two don't match or are invalid emails, but it just won't display them in the form fields like the other fields will on an update.

Edit: mostly full code is here: http://pastebin.com/q8PR97fn

Comment: no end quote on user_email in the last line? should be `'user_email'` instead of `'user_email`

Comment: It sounds like you have put your update code after the place WP goes and gets the users email address. Check the flow of the code in the script you are changing, or the script that calls your script.

Comment: @Déjàvu that was just an error in simplifying the code for this question, oops!

Comment: Sounds like a problem in the execution order.

Comment: How would I find out about execution order, is there anything in the codex about stuff like that?

Comment: Yes this seems to be execution order issue. Can you please post your complete PHP post you are using for updation? Starting from global variables declaration

Comment: @ZameerKhan I just edited the code into the OP.

Comment: `wpdb::escape` is deprecated since version 3.6! Use `wpdb::prepare()` or `esc_sql()` instead.

Comment: Turn on `WP_DEBUG` from `wp-config.php`.

Answer (score 0):

Do give a try to separate global variable like this and check if it is happening again:

```
<?php
global $user_email;
get_currentuserinfo();
echo "Email address is: " . $user_email;
?>
```